# Insert row after set number of rows 100 times

Tags: excel, vba

I need to insert 1 row every 7 rows in a sheet starting on row 15 and do this 100 times. Would select row 15,22,29,etc.. and insert.
 I have tried the following, but it stops after inserting the first insert.
'

```
Sub bugfix()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A15")
    While rng.Value <> ""
        rng.Offset(7).Resize(1).EntireRow.Insert
        Set rng = rng.Offset(810)
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: That looks like VB / VBA. Where's the Sql :) (Welcome to StackOverflow - please note that folk tend to follow tags in which they are interested, so adding a tag like `Sql` will attract people skilled in RDBMS's, and who are not necessarily skilled in spreadsheets)

Comment: Yep, absolutely correct. Can you add those tags?

Comment: `Range("A15")` and `rng.Offset` seem to imply VBA for Excel. Updated tag (and removed SQL tag).

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a `For` loop? Are you overwriting something that already exists and hence checking something does (`rng.Value <> ""`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop:

> For x = 15 to 715 step 7
>
> ```
>  Rows(x & ":" & x).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
> ```
>
> Next x

Comment: Sorry, I tagged as per the auto-recommended tags that popped up with my question.  My first time on the forum, I'm learning as I go.  I didn't use a loop cause I don't know even the basics, I'm just copy pasting and trying to figure it out...

Comment: You're welcome. If you like the answer, please vote up and accept it by clicking the up arrow and check mark next to it. Thank you.

Comment: If I could ask another, in each inserted row on column I, I need to insert the text "Total".  Can this be done in the same loop?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own last question on the comment above.

```
For x = 15 To 815 Step 8

 Rows(x & ":" & x).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
 Cells(x, 9).Value = "Total"

Next x
```